# Get a sitemap in ASP.NET part from Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I have a website which has two parts: the first one was made in Umbraco CMS (v4.7), the second one in ASP.NET.
The task is to get a sitemap (not just names of pages, I need some parameters as well) in ASP.NET part from Umbraco.

I have only one idea how I can do such thing - write an XML file in Umbraco and then open it in ASP.NET, but I did not find any way how exactly do it.

If you have any ideas, please help.

Many Thanks

Vlad

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this...

```
using umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory;

public string CreateSitemap()
{
    var temp = "<ul>" + sitemap(-1) + "</ul>";
    return temp;
}

public string sitemap(int nodeID)
{
    var rootNode = new umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory.Node(nodeID);
    string sitemapstring = "<li><a href=" + rootNode.Id + ">" + rootNode.Name + "</a></li>";
    if(rootNode.Children.Count>0)
    {
        sitemapstring+="<ul>";
        foreach(Node node in rootNode.Children)
        {
            sitemapstring += sitemap(node.Id);
        }
        sitemapstring+="</ul>";
    }
    return sitemapstring;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check out the Razor edition of [this sitemap package](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/cultiv-search-engine-sitemap) (at the bottom)?